# How to edit LibreOffice 4 with MsOffice Word corrections?

Tags: text-processing, libreoffice

I've received a file in docx. with some corrections made in MsOffice Word in the mode of correction (edition). How I can accept them in Libreoffice4 in Linux?

Comment: What precise version of LibreOffice do you have? Please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: I recommend upgrading your LibreOffice (to version 5)

Answer (score 1):

This function is called *Track Changes* and for sure implemented in LibreOffice 5, you can accept by click right mouse button on changes and check accept. 
[here is help site](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Accepting_or_Rejecting_Changes)

In LibreOffice 4 i don't remember, but there might be option in Edit->Changes menu